# Flattening a nested json while printing outer json using jq

Tags: jq

I have a file like below (excerpt)

```
cat input.json
{
    "Metrics": [
        {
            "Namespace": "CWAgent",
            "MetricName": "disk_used_percent",
            "Dimensions": [
                {
                    "Name": "path",
                    "Value": "/aem"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "host",
                    "Value": "uat2-author01.uat.cloud.abc.com.au"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "device",
                    "Value": "mapper/aem-aem"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "fstype",
                    "Value": "ext4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Namespace": "CWAgent",
            "MetricName": "mem_used_percent",
            "Dimensions": [
                {
                    "Name": "host",
                    "Value": "uat2-dispatch02.uat.cloud.abc.com.au"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the "Dimensions" is a list of json objects of varying length. I am required to print each objects under "Metrics" in a single line like below -

```
CWAgent|disk_used_percent|path:/aem|host:uat2-author01.uat.cloud.abc.com.au|device:mapper/aem-aem|fstype:ext4
CWAgent|mem_used_percent|host:uat2-dispatch02.uat.cloud.abc.com.au
```

I used this -

```
cat input.json | jq -r ".Metrics[] | .Namespace + \"|\" + .MetricName + \"|\" + (.Dimensions[] | .Name + \":\" + .Value + \"|\")"
```

And the output is like below:

```
CWAgent|disk_used_percent|path:/aem|
CWAgent|disk_used_percent|host:uat2-author01.uat.cloud.abc.com.au|
CWAgent|disk_used_percent|device:mapper/aem-aem|
CWAgent|disk_used_percent|fstype:ext4|
CWAgent|mem_used_percent|host:uat2-dispatch02.uat.cloud.abc.com.au|
```

As you can see, we are getting 4 lines for first object each having different object under Dimensions. Can anyone please suggest what will be the jq command to get desired output. I am novice in jq and wasted too much time on this experimenting.

Thanks,
Bijitesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```bash
jq -r '.Metrics[] | [.Namespace, .MetricName] + (.Dimensions | map("\(.Name):\(.Value)")) | join("|")' input.json
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm. Being novice I came across this map function for first time. Could you pls refer me some link to read more about it?

Comment: @BijiteshKundu https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)

Comment: Hi @oguz ismail - Have one further query. If I am required to print only the json object under "Dimensions" which has "Name" as "host", how that can be achieved? With the example above, the requirement is to print this - ```CWAgent|disk_used_percent|host:uat2-author01.uat.cloud.abc.com.au```

Comment: @BijiteshKundu `jq -r '.Metrics[] | [.Namespace, .MetricName, (.Dimensions | from_entries.host | "host:\(.)")] | join("|")'`